# Inequality on Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a complex Hilbert space. Is it possible that under certain conditions $$|\langle Tx,y\rangle|\leq \|T\||\langle x,y\rangle|$$ for all $x,y\in H$ with $x\not\perp y$ and $T\in B(H)$? Or actually, is this true for all Hilbert space $H$ and bounded linear operator $T$ on $H$? I couldn't find a counterexample.

Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: Of course it is possible. Try the reals. It is not possible generally. In the plane take $T$ to be a 90 degree rotation, $x=e_1, y=e_2$.

Comment: For $T(x)=x$ (ie $T$ being the identity), your inequality becomes an identity :)

Comment: In your example $e_1,\;e_2$ are orthogonal but I want $x\not\perp y$.

Comment: Of course, when $T=I$ this is true. Now, is it true for any operator $T$ on $H$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the inequality holds whenever $ \langle x, y \rangle \neq 0$ it will hold when  $ \langle x, y \rangle = 0$ also: Replace $y$ by $y+\frac   1n x$ and take limit as $n \to \infty$. Hence the comment by copper.hat provides a  counter-example.

Comment: You are right. Now, if $\|T\|<1$ or $\|T\|$ is sufficiently small. Is it possible? or do you have a counterexample?. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @AndrésFelipe If you have one counter-example you can get any number by just multiplying $T$ by  a positive number. So there are examples with $\|T\|$ as small as you want.